# Data from getServerSideProps not showing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from `getServerSideProps` and I do get the data in console but when I try to show said data it won't show.

Please know i'm getting the response from the api but im unable to show the data on the frontend.

Where I'm fetching and passing it to another component.

Where I'm fetching data

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const postData = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/root/").then(
    (res) => res.json() // Fecthing data and turning response to json
  );

  return {
    props: {
      postData, // Returing feteched data as prop
    },
  };
}
```

Passing as a prop

```
{user ? (
 <Reddit auth={auth} user={user} posts={postData} />
) : (
 <Login auth={auth} />
)}
```

Here's my `Reddit.js`

```
import Header from "../components/header/Header";

function Reddit({ auth, user, posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header auth={auth} user={user} />
      {posts.map((i) => {
        <h1>{i.title}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Reddit;
```

component where im passing the data as a prop

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Reddit from "../components/Reddit";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import Login from "../components/auth/Login";

import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

import "firebase/auth";

// Initializing app
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAssbNkDI_99hrs5oBp3DUYbSo7InqY-a8",
  authDomain: "reddit-clone-1f12.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "reddit-clone-1f12",
  storageBucket: "reddit-clone-1f12.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "166670883433",
  appId: "1:166670883433:web:f24816c8fe909b0f89e0f8",
});

// Getting authentication api
const auth = getAuth();

export default function Home({ postData }) {
  console.log(postData);
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth); // Checking user's authentication state

  return (
    <div className="h-screen bg-black text-white">
      <Head>
        <title>Reddit - Dive into anything!</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.svg" />
      </Head>

      {/* If user is logged in, show <Reddit /> otherwise show <Login /> */}
      {user ? (
        <Reddit auth={auth} user={user} posts={postData} />
      ) : (
        <Login auth={auth} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/root/");
  const postData = await response.json();

  return { props: { postData } };
}
```

Comment: why you are using `await` and `then` at the same time ? Try to send data like this:
`const postData = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/root/");

return {
    props: {
      postData.json(),
    },
  };`

Comment: When i do it like that it's giving me a syntax error

Comment: `const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/root/");
const postData = await response.json()  return {     props: {       postData,     },   };`

This should work.

Comment: It still donst seem to work, its not giving me an error but its not shoing the text either

Comment: can you create a simple code sandbox and show us your code.

Comment: I'm very sorry but i don't know how to

Comment: you can check this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-rgb-d6dk5?file=/pages/index.js. It's working fine.  so it means there is something wrong with your backend, where you are fetching data.

Comment: @SajawalHassan Are you getting the expected response data from the API call inside `getServerSideProps`? Also, could you provide the full code for the component where you're passing the data as a prop?

Comment: @juliomalves yes i'm getting the expected response the main problem is that when i try to show said data it done not show without any errors and i have updated the main post showing the full component where im passing the data as a prop

Comment: Oh im very sorry but the reason data was not showing on the fontend was because of a typo, again i apologize for wasting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in reddit.js

instead of

```
import Header from "../components/header/Header";

function Reddit({ auth, user, posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header auth={auth} user={user} />
      {posts?.map((i) => {
        <h1>{i.title}</h1>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Reddit;
```

try this

```
import Header from "../components/header/Header";

function Reddit({ auth, user, posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header auth={auth} user={user} />
      {posts?.map((i) => (
        <h1>{i.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Reddit;
```

Comment: what typo? can you be more specific?

Comment: change the curly braces to perenthisis

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
export function getServerSideProps() {
  const postData = fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/root/").then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );

  return {
    props: {
      postData, 
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Your code also done not seem to work it's giving me an error saying "Error: Error serializing `.postData` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
Reason: `object` ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types."

Comment: can you show me data in API?

Comment: here you go hope your asking for data and not it's actual code "[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "This is a meme",
        "img_url": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/17/26/f9/1726f9d7b50bd7ef2d077a7fb3a2e577.jpg",
        "message": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Updated title",
        "img_url": "https://i.redd.it/k6xyqc2otg181.jpg",
        "message": ""
    }
]"

Comment: Hey sorry but the reason it was not showing is because there was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the extra braces from the postData in the return props. I imagine it is one level too deep.

```
  return {
    props: postData
  };
```

Explanation:

```
// Your postData object probably looks like:
const postData = { auth: ..., user: ..., posts: ... }

// If you deserialize with extra braces it will fail
const { auth, user } = { postData } // Fails
const { auth, user } = postData // Succeeds
```

Comment: Hello this does not seem to work it's giving me an error "Error: Error serializing props returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
Reason: Props must be returned as a plain object from getServerSideProps: `{ props: { ... } }` (received: `[object Array]`)"

Comment: Hey the reason it was not showing is because of a typo again sorry